# barcode scan is not working for full AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, barcode

I have added AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to my whole view still when I'm trying to scan the barcode , it scans if i place the barcode at the centre of view. Please help me with the solution

Answer (score 4):

When AVCapture scan for QRCode,there are there squares in the corners to help locate the QRCode.So you can scan for QRCode anywhere in the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer,and scan for more than one QRCode a time.
But there is no square to help locate barcode,instead, AVCapture scan for multiple lines which cross over the center of **RectOfInterest**.When a line cross over all of the lines of a Barcode,the AVCapture recognize this BarCode.So , if your barcode is in the corner of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, and you don't change the default set of RectOfInterest,then you can't scan this barcode.

To fix this problem :

1. you can draw a Rect in the center of  AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to hint user put barcode in the center.
2. set RectOfInterest at corner of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer,so you can only scan the barcode in the corder.

Comment: WoW.. after finding so many stuff.. this solved my problem. Exactly, this how it should be. If we understand then, those two points can solve a lot of problems

Comment: @wj2061 Can you please suggest me what changes I need for this issue in my code? Here is my function - https://pastebin.com/embed_js/d2CvB9CU

Comment: it seems this has been changed recently. According to [TN2325](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2325/_index.html) there should only be center scan lines when both 1D and 2D barcodes are enabled, but on my device I get additional scan lines as well. This is problematic when drawing a center line/rect but 1D codes are also detected above and below this rect/line. Does anyone know if additional scan lines can be disabled?